# Section/Aside (HTML5)

Tags: html, html5, section

I read about `<section>` and `<aside>` on the WC3 site a whole ago, but I can't remember if an `<aside>` should be placed inside a `<section>` or directly beneath it. Does anybody know?

E.g. Should it be like this?:

```
<section>...</section>
```

Or like this:

```
<section>...<aside>...</aside>...</section>
```

Thank you

Comment: Seems like it would be quicker to go back to the W3C page you saw it on and see what it actually says than to post a question and wait for an answer.

Comment: Nup lol. I've been looking for it all night while waiting for an answer, and couldn't find it. I only stumbled upon it in the first place by accident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place an *aside* inside *section* if you like. It just indicates that the content is not directly related to the current article hence it being aside. Moreover, you can even have a *section* inside a *aside* tag if you want to break up the content within it.

I usually think of *aside* as having more of a semantic meaning and *section* more of a presentational function. this way you can decide which is best for the content you're trying to display.

Comment: Section isn't more related with presentational function. For that you have DIV. Sections are, semantically speaking, sections. :)

Answer (score 1):

To me it makes the most sense to have the aside within the section that it relates to, if that is the intent of the content. However, it's pretty flexible - there are no hard rules.